# Determining nested consumer completion

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

How do you synchronize overall consumer completion for a large number of of nested producer-consumers?

For example, let's say you have a "USPS" system implementation:

1. Run a `Backoffice.start` function which starts a Runnable
   `SubOffice.startMailProcessing` in my SubOffice objects
2. All of my
   `SubOffice` object consumers "start" functions now start processing
   mail
3. Each `SubOffice` object then does its own fanout to consumers
   which starts a `Runnable` of `MailTruck.deliverMail`
4. Wait for all above mail
   processes to process the day's mail and for all trucks to deliver
   mail
5. Repeat

I can envision a few solutions:

1. It seems like one way is to `shutdown` an executor and wait for all
   of those `Runnable`'s to complete, but that's not ideal because you
   have to recreate those threads from scratch for the executor every
   repeat cycle.
2. Java 8 provides a construct `CompletableFuture` to be able to solve this. However, with a heavily nested producer-consumer pattern, one might need to implement "callback hell" to bubble up all of your    future's to the initial producer.
3. Use a `Phaser` (i.e. the `CountDownLatch` on
   steroids) and register all of the consumers with the phaser, and
   deregister when complete, while making the main thread wait until
   it's complete.
4. Some of the reactive-manifesto based technologies, like RxJava seem to handle some of these types of cases.

I would imagine awaiting completion and then cycling, like in the above example, to repeat a cycle is a common problem. 
What is the standard solution or architecture for this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rely on Java8's `CompletableFuture` you can flatten nested futures into a single one using `CompletableFuture.thenCompose()`. (This is equivalent to what is usually called flatmap in more functional oriented languages).

For combining a list of futures into a single future you can use `CompletableFuture.allOf()`, which return a future that completes when all of the individual futures completed.

Combined these two methods allow to to avoid callback hell by composing a future out of the various futures from all of your sub-tasks.

Comment: So, you're suggesting bubbling up CompletableFutures and composing a single monolith CompletableFuture and then calling join on it at the end to wait for all of the consumers to complete? I can see how that would work, but I can't say I'm completely convinced. What would have been done before Java 8 to do this? Phasers and Countdown latches?